# Join annotations in Django without raw SQL

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that has arbitrary key/value pairs (attributes) associated with it.  I'd like to have the option of sorting by those dynamic attributes.  Here's what I came up with:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  pass

class Attribute(models.Model):
  item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='attributes')
  key = models.CharField()
  value = models.CharField()

def get_sorted_items():
  return Item.objects.all().annotate(
      first=models.select_attribute('first'),
      second=models.select_attribute('second'),
  ).order_by('first', 'second')

def select_attribute(attribute):
  return expressions.RawSQL("""
      select app_attribute.value from app_attribute
      where app_attribute.item_id = app_item.id
      and app_attribute.key = %s""", (attribute,))
```

This works, but it has a bit of raw SQL in it, so it makes my co-workers wary.  Is it possible to do this without raw SQL?  Can I make use of Django's ORM to simplify this?

I would expect something like this to work, but it doesn't:

```
def get_sorted_items():
  return Item.objects.all().annotate(
      first=Attribute.objects.filter(key='first').values('value'),
      second=Attribute.objects.filter(key='second').values('value'),
  ).order_by('first', 'second')
```

Comment: Can you provide the class definition for your `queryset`? Is there any relation between the `queryset` class and the `Item`/`Attributes`? If there isn't any relation I think `RawSQL` is the only way. If there is I can provide you a full answer with several examples on how it can be achieved.

Comment: Oops.  It's supposed to be Item.objects.all()

Answer (score 1):

### Approach 1

Using Djagno 1.8+ [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions)
(see also [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#query-expressions))

```
items = Item.objects.all().annotate(
    first=models.Case(models.When(attribute__key='first', then=models.F('attribute__value')), default=models.Value('')),
    second=models.Case(models.When(attribute__key='second', then=models.F('attribute__value')), default=models.Value(''))
).distinct()

for item in items:
    print item.first, item.second
```

### Approach 2

Using [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with custom `models.Prefetch` object

```
keys = ['first', 'second']
items = Item.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch('attributes',
        queryset=Attribute.objects.filter(key__in=keys),
        to_attr='prefetched_attrs'),
)
```

This way every `item` from the `queryset` will contain a list under the `.prefetched_attrs` attribute.

This list will contains all filtered-item-related attributes.

Now, because you want to get the `attribute.value`, you can implement something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    #...
    def get_attribute(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return next((attr.value for attr in self.prefetched_attrs if attr.key == key), default)
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('You didnt prefetch any attributes')

#and the usage will be:
for item in items:
    print item.get_attribute('first'), item.get_attribute('second')
```

Some notes about the differences in using both approaches.

- you have a one idea better control over the filtering process using the approach with the custom `Prefetch` object. The conditional-expressions approach is one idea harder to be optimized IMHO.
- with `prefetch_related` you get the whole attribute object, not just the `value` you are interested in.
- Django executes `prefetch_related` after the `queryset` is being evaluated, which means a second query is being executed for each clause in the prefetch_related call. On one way this can be good, because it this keeps the main `queryset` untouched from the filters and thus not additional clauses like `.distinct()` are needed.
- `prefetch_related` always put the returned objects into a list, its not very convenient to use when you have prefetchs returning 1 element per object. So additional model methods are required in order to use with pleasure.

Comment: Do both approaches allow you to sort the way I do in my example?

Comment: Only the first one

Comment: You may as well delete the second one then, because my question is about sorting.  Getting the attributes through prefetch_related is otherwise pretty obvious.  Though I suppose you're creating a better interface for it or something?  I suppose both of these could be used together?